# Nativescript Sidekick cloud build error. Available builds being counted down too

Tags: nativescript

I’m experiencing some issues on my Sidekick’s iOS cloud build, where in it says that it built successfully then notifies an error message. Hence, no downloaded ipa archive.

My available cloud builds are being counted down due to ‘successful’ build. But there’s no ipa file downloaded. I feel like I’m being ripped off. :(

Details.

iOS cloud build
-Release box checked with Uglify, Snapshot, AOT checked too.
-used an iOS Adhoc distribution profile.

Error Message. (I don’t have any proxies as far as I know.)

```
[18-04-12 19:19:37.347] Build failed. read ECONNRESET
[18-04-12 19:32:10.741] (CLI) (node:17386) Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
[18-04-12 19:32:12.642] (CLI) (node:17386) Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
[18-04-12 19:32:13.803] (CLI) (node:17386) Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
[18-04-12 19:32:21.098] (CLI) (node:17386) Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
[18-04-12 19:32:21.110] (CLI) (node:17386) Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
[18-04-12 19:32:21.706] (CLI) (node:17386) Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:580:26)
[18-04-12 19:39:26.066] Build failed. read ECONNRESET
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build is actually successful and that's why your remaining builds are decreasing. Your build result download request is interrupted while NativeScript Sidekick downloads your ipa. This can happen if you have network request restrictions.

You can get the result download url from the detailed build logs and try to download the ipa manually. The build result download url will look like this https://[s3-bucket-name].s3.amazonaws.com/[some-random-string]/[project-name].ipa?[some-s3-temp-credentials]
You should just get the detailed logs and search for .ipa in them to find the download url.

How to enable detailed logs:

1. Open [path-to-installed-nativescript-cli]/config/config.json
2. Change the DEBUG option to true
3. The config should look like this:

```
{
    "DEBUG": true,
    "TYPESCRIPT_COMPILER_OPTIONS": {},
    "CI_LOGGER": false,
    "ANDROID_DEBUG_UI_MAC": "Google Chrome",
    "USE_POD_SANDBOX": false,
    "DISABLE_HOOKS": false
}
```

If you still can't download your ipa, you should try to use another network to see if the problem is in your network.

If you manage to download the ipa manually from the download link, you could submit a bug report in https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues.

If the suggested above does not help you to resolve the issue, I still recommend that you open a new issue in the repository mentioned above.